# How do I escape a mysql "search / like" query properly?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

## Summary

I am currently using `"$search_field LIKE '$this->db->escape_like_str($search_string)%'";` to escape dynamically created search queries. The resulting SQL statements created do not produce any errors but also do not produce any results. Below is a detailed description of what I am doing.

## Details

I am using jqGrid and its search feature. When the user enters search terms it posts the `$filters` json object to my server. I then parse it and create an SQL statement to get the data requested.

Here is the code for escaping the incoming search data (this is also the problem area):

```
$search_string_like = $this->CI->db->escape_like_str($search_string);
$operator['bw'] = "$search_field LIKE '$search_string_like%'"; //begins with
```

Here is the resulting SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM player_data_temp_table
WHERE first_name LIKE '\'zech\'%' AND last_name LIKE '\'camp\'%'
ORDER BY date_won desc
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

This query doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't work. When I run a similar query directly in phpmyadmin I get, `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).` even though I know there are results to be found. If I simply remove the backslashes and single-quotes from `first_name LIKE '\'zech\'%'` to make it `first_name LIKE 'zech%'` I then get the expected results. My concern is that this is no longer properly escaped, right?

## Code Used to Build the Query

**Summary**

A variable, `$filters`, with data such as this `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"first_name","op":"bw","data":"zech"}]}` is passed into `build_where_clause($filters)`. `build_where_clause` returns the full `$where` statement and is then used in the Model to create the final SQL search statement.

**jqgrid_lib.php**

```
class jqgrid_lib 
{
private $CI;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}

/**
 * Function takes a json string with search rules and turns it into an sql statement.
 *
 * To use this function make sure you set stringResult: true, see example below:
 *   $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true});
 * @param   json string     
 * @author zechdc
 */
public function build_where_clause($filters)
{
    $sql_fragments = array();

    $filters = json_decode($filters);
    $rules = $filters->rules;
    $group_op = $filters->groupOp;

    //loop through each rule and create an sql statement
    foreach($rules as $rule)
    {
        $temp_sql = $this->create_search_field($rule->field, $rule->data, $rule->op);
        array_push($sql_fragments, $temp_sql);
    }

    //combine all sql fragments with the group_operator
    $data['sql'] = implode(' ' . $group_op . ' ', $sql_fragments);

    return $data;
}

/**
 * Takes a field, string and search condition and turns it into a sql search statement
 *
 * To use this function make sure you set stringResult: true, see example below:
 *   $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true});
 * @param   json string 
 * @return  string  
 * @author  zechdc
 */
public function create_search_field($search_field, $search_string, $search_operator)
{   
    //$search_field = $this->CI->db->escape($search_field); //escaping the column breaks it.
    $search_string = $this->CI->db->escape($search_string);
    $search_string_like = $this->CI->db->escape_like_str($search_string);
    //$search_string_like = $search_string;

    $operator['eq'] = "$search_field=$search_string"; //equal to
    $operator['ne'] = "$search_field<>$search_string"; //not equal to
    $operator['lt'] = "$search_field < $search_string"; //less than
    $operator['le'] = "$search_field <= $search_string "; //less than or equal to
    $operator['gt'] = "$search_field > $search_string"; //less than
    $operator['ge'] = "$search_field >= $search_string "; //less than or equal to
    $operator['bw'] = "$search_field LIKE '$search_string_like%'"; //begins with
    $operator['bn'] = "$search_field NOT LIKE '$search_string_like%'"; //not begins with
    $operator['in'] = "$search_field IN ($search_string)"; //in
    $operator['ni'] = "$search_field NOT IN ($search_string)"; //not in
    $operator['ew'] = "$search_field LIKE '%$search_string_like'"; //ends with
    $operator['en'] = "$search_field NOT LIKE '%$search_string_like%'"; //not ends with
    $operator['cn'] = "$search_field LIKE '%$search_string_like%'"; //in
    $operator['nc'] = "$search_field NOT LIKE '%$search_string_like%'"; //not in
    $operator['nu'] = "$search_field IS NULL"; //is null
    $operator['nn'] = "$search_field IS NOT NULL"; //is not null

    if(isset($operator[$search_operator])) 
    {
        //set the sql search statement
        return $operator[$search_operator];
    } 
}
}
```

**Model**

```
/*
 * Gets all columns from table with limit and sort order set dynamically
 */
function get_specific($sidx, $sord, $start, $limit, $where = NULL)
{
    $result = FALSE;

    if($where)
    {
        $where = ' WHERE ' . $where;
    }

    // usually I dont do select all but since this whole table is temp and only holds the needed data
    // then just do select all.
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM player_data_temp_table
            $where
            ORDER BY $sidx $sord
            LIMIT $start , $limit"; 

    $q = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        $result = $q->result();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

## UPDATE / Answer:

It looks like I fixed the issue. In the model I removed the hand made $sql statement and replaced it with

```
    if($where)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $this->db->order_by($sidx, $sord);
    $q = $this->db->get('player_data_temp_table', $limit, $start);
```

That seemed to properly escape all the variables including my column names in the $where statement.

Comment: There's a problem with this clause: "I simply remove the slashes from `first_name LIKE '\'zech\'%'` to make it `first_name LIKE 'zech%'`". I imagine you mean "I simply remove the backslashes **and single-quotes**"?

Comment: Just for clarification, is the query string you provided before or after your escape_like_str() function call?

Comment: @ruakh yes you are correct, I will update my post.

Comment: @MattMoore The Query String I provided is after i used `escape_like_str()` I reorganized my question to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: As a means of testing replace the '\'zech\'%' so it's "'zech'%", I'm pretty sure sql doesn't deal with \' in the way you're expecting.

Comment: @SOliver Using the sql like you suggested: `first_name LIKE "'zech'%"` still does not return the expected results.

Comment: Can you post the entire build of your query string? My first guess would be that sql is reading your \' as part of the string and thus it isn't returning any of the results. Why that is will be hard to deduce without the entire string creation.

Comment: @MattMoore I will Post the entire function that builds the Query String

Answer (score 1):

[Manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html):

> $this->db->escape_like_str() This method should be used when strings are to be used in LIKE conditions so that LIKE wildcards ('%', '_') in the string are also properly escaped.

```
$search = '20% raise';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%'";
```

So you're doing it right in your last two lines of code.

---

What does the following code do for you?

```
$search_string = 'zech';
$search_string_like = $this->CI->db->escape_like_str($search_string);
$operator['bw'] = "$search_field LIKE '$search_string_like%'";
```

Comment: I thought that was correct but its not working. Using that code you posted gives me something like `first_name LIKE '\'zech\'%'`. It runs with no errors but doesn't return any results. If I change it to `first_name LIKE 'zech%'` it returns the expected results. That is why I am confused. I thought I was doing it right by using `$this->db->escape_like_str($search)` but it doesn't work. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @zechdc what are the contents of $search?

Comment: Well in the example in my comment above, the contents of `$search` would be `zech`

Comment: @zechdc: You should check that. It really sounds like the contents of `$search` are actually `'zech'` (with superfluous single-quotes).

Comment: @zechdc try `var_dump($search)`. Perhaps the quotes are already around the search string, causing them to be escaped. Edit: GMTA. :-P

Comment: @CodeCaster I just ran `var_dump($search)` and it returned `string(4) "zech"`. Is that the problem?

Comment: @CodeCaster The code you just posted in your answer update is used to set the search string based on what operator is passed into the function, it would return: `first_name LIKE '\'zech\'%'`

Comment: @zechdc I cannot believe that the literal code I posted produces the query you posted. The escape function has nothing to escape, so it should return the string as-is. What does `var_dump($this->CI->db->escape_like_str('zech'))` output?

Comment: @CodeCaster I just ran the following line `var_dump($this->CI->db->escape_like_str('zech'));` and it returned `string(4) "zech"`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6023/discussion-between-zechdc-and-codecaster)